# How to create a Two-column feeds layout like Google+ using Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter, feed

It should be responsive so that on smaller screens the element on right comes down as the second element.

Comment: This is basic Bootstrap grid system - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic - Please read the docs and give it a go before asking here. If you've already tried something and it has not worked, show us. Jake745 has been kind enough to answer, but bear in mind that others probably won't. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/NBboOxAwuf)

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
                Left text
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
                 Right Data
             </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Apparently this is not what I was talking about it. Results should append from the database. So like you wrote my each element has classes col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6. But I want to know how can I append them correctly first to the first column and next on the second column